# explain why this resolve will not return a promise? JS

Tags: javascript, promise, resolve

I can't seem to figure out why this will not work, the first example works perfectly fine. Repeating the same resolve method for the second example doesn't work? I've tried everything in documentation and can't figure out why, it always returns an empty {}, and yes it console.logs perfectly fine within the local function.

Example 1 *This works perfectly fine, result returns url link in console*

```
 function searchStockx(searchText){ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://xw7sbct9v6-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/products/query",
        headers: stockxheaders,
        qs: stockxalgolia,
        json: {"params":"query=" + searchText + "&facets=*&filters="}
      },
        function(err, res, body){

        let stockXurl = body.hits[0].url
        resolve(stockXurl)

    })
})
}                 
   app.post('/', (async(req, res) => {
   searchText = (req.body.input)
   result = await searchStockx(searchText)

   res.send(result



}))
```

Example 2 *Same resolve as above, just different variables, returns empty {} (undefined) in terminal*

```
function getGoatSize(slug){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://www.goat.com/api/v1/product_templates/" + slug + "/show_v2",
            headers: goatGETHeaders
          },
          function(err, res, body){

            let json = JSON.parse(body)
            let goatSizes = json.availableSizesNewV2
            let goatPic = json.pictureUrl




            resolve(goatPic)

            })
        })
 }


app.post('/', (async(req, res) => {
   searchText = (req.body.input)
    searchStockx(searchText)
    result = await getGoatSize(goatPic)
    res.send(result)



}))
```

Comment: Avoid putting business logic in the non-promise callback. Do only `resolve(res)`. Then do the `JSON.parse` and field accesses in a `then` callback or after an `await`, where exceptions will be properly handled.

Comment: Second @Bergi. log `goatPic` the line before `resolve(goatPic)`, check its value.

Comment: it logs fine, returns what is it supposed to @Mahdi

Comment: @Bergi should the .then callback be placed in the app.post? thank you for your response

Comment: Probably in `getGoatSize` itself if you don't want to repeat it between call sites

Comment: think about https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143

Comment: @bergi have reordered using promise, then parsing and .then, thanks for that info. still same results of not being able to get anything to return outside of the function.

Comment: @Estradiaz thanks I have been reading into using fetch